# Installed angular version 6.1.3 but ng version shows version Angular CLI: 9.0.4

Tags: angular

I had Angular CLI: 9.0.4 installed on my system and I needed to downgrade it to version 6 so I used following commands in order

1. `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm install -g @angular/cli@6.1.3`

but `ng version` command still shows `Angular CLI: 9.0.4`

[image]

How to properly downgrade angular from version 9 to version 6?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you close the VS Code post doing all commands run ?

Comment: have you ever installed the angular cli with the global flag?

Comment: @Dreamweaver No.. but using ng version just after the `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` resulted in command not found then npm install -g @angular/cli@6.1.3 again resulted in angular version 9.0.4

Comment: @fredrik I don't remember

Comment: @Arjun Not sure why it behaving like this, but npm i -g @angular/cli@6.1.3 this should install 6.1.3,.
I have one doubt event though your global package is on latest, you can still compile and work with older projects, And in case you are building new it's good to have latest version.

Comment: @Dreamweaver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60495548/angular-node-modules-angular-material-index-d-ts-is-not-a-module/60495555#60495555..this is the reason i'm trying to downgrade angular version

Comment: In that case, I feel u have existing project and you want to integrate the angular-material. So, why not hard code the version in package json to whatever version you want. That will definitely work. Remove package.json.lock file before npm install

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in this sequence and then check the version

1. npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
2. npm cache clean --force
3. npm cache verify
4. npm install -g @angular/cli@6.1.3