# Angular: node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use angular material to implement an autocomplete but I'm getting the error

```
ERROR in app.module.ts:22:8 - error TS2306: File '/home/user/MedvibesWebRepo/medvibes/medvibes-web/medvibes/medvibes-main-web/src/main/webapp/node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module.

22 } from '@angular/material/';
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

index.d.ts only contains comments and I checked app.module.ts's 22nd line and it doesn't contain `'@angular/material/';` I don't understand where  the  `22 } from '@angular/material/';` error comes from? How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is related to how to import module from angular/material.

For example: if you want to import MatSliderModule:

for angular 9,

`import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';`

in angular 8 or below, you can still do

`import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material';`

Comment: but any shortcut for that as if we want import multiple module then how to do that ?

Comment: on angular upgrade guild, https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0. if you select `I use Angular Material`. It says `Instead of importing from @angular/material, you should import deeply from the specific component. E.g. @angular/material/button. ng update will do this automatically for you`

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is related to the  Angular version you are using.
for example, if you want to import MatSliderModule, for angular 9:

```
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
```

for earlier versions, you don't need to specify the exact path:

```
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material';
```

will do just fine